# how to solve the error each child must lay out exactly once and invalid value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i have been trying to make an app that has a listview and ontap it goes to details page and shows info that got from navigator (by a datamodel)here is the code i have tried everything in the internet but it still has this two errors (its not a bug)

**code**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:train/pages/dishdatamodel.dart';
    import 'package:train/pages/dishdetail.dart';
    import 'home.dart';

    class Favorites extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
         _FavoritesState createState() => _FavoritesState();
    }

    class _FavoritesState extends State<Favorites> {
      var itemcount =4;
      static List<String> dishname = ['MEXICAN BURGER','PASTA','DESERT','ICE CREAM','BIRIYANI','EGG BIRIYANI','CHICKEN BIRIYANI'];
      static List<String> dishprice = ['12\$', '20\$', '15\$', '10\$', '30\$', '35\$', '40\$'];
      static List urlImages = [
        'https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/442072a900a8a1c2cc10.jpg''https://pixabay.com/photos/cake-piece-plate-dessert-pastry-1971552/',
        'https://pixabay.com/photos/cake-piece-plate-dessert-pastry-1971552/',
        'https://pixabay.com/photos/cake-piece-plate-dessert-pastry-1971552/',
        'https://pixabay.com/photos/cake-piece-plate-dessert-pastry-1971552/',
        'https://pixabay.com/photos/cake-piece-plate-dessert-pastry-1971552/',
        'https://pixabay.com/photos/cake-piece-plate-dessert-pastry-1971552/',
      ];


    final List<dishdatamodel>dishdata = List.generate(
          dishname.length,
          (index) =>dishdatamodel('${dishname[index]}', '${urlImages[index]}',
              '${dishname[index]}description.......', '${dishprice[index]}'));
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: dishdata.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
                  return Card(
                    color: Colors.deepOrange,
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(dishdata[index].name),
                      trailing: Text(dishdata[index].price),
                      leading: ConstrainedBox(
                        constraints: BoxConstraints(
                          minHeight: 40,
                          minWidth: 40,
                          maxHeight: 50,
                          maxWidth: 50,
                        ),
                        child: Image.network(dishdata[index].imageurl),
                      ),
                      onTap: (){
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => dishdetail(dishdatamode: dishdata[index],)));
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                })
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

here is the errors

```
 ======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
    The following RangeError was thrown building _BodyBuilder:
    RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..5: 6
    
    The relevant error-causing widget was: 
      Scaffold file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/android%20studio%20projets/train/lib/nav.dart:29:12
    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
    #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:177:60)
    #1      new _FavoritesState.<anonymous closure> (package:train/pages/favorites.dart:26:65)
    #2      new _GrowableList.generate (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:128:28)
    #3      new _FavoritesState (package:train/pages/favorites.dart:24:44)
    #4      Favorites.createState (package:train/pages/favorites.dart:8:36)
    
    ====================================================================================================
    
    ======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
    The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
    Each child must be laid out exactly once.
    
    The _ScaffoldLayout custom multichild layout delegate forgot to lay out the following child: 
      _ScaffoldSlot.body: RenderErrorBox#14191 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body
        constraints: MISSING
        size: MISSING
    The relevant error-causing widget was: 
      Scaffold file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/android%20studio%20projets/train/lib/nav.dart:29:12
    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
    #0      MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:246:11)
    #1      MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:259:8)
    #2      RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:402:14)
    #3      RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
    #4      PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:884:18)
    ...
    The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#dc3f5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    .  needs compositing
    .  parentData: <none> (can use size)
    .  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, h=850.9)
    .  size: Size(392.7, 850.9)
    RenderObject: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#dc3f5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
      needs compositing
      parentData: <none> (can use size)
      constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, h=850.9)
      size: Size(392.7, 850.9)
    .  child 1: RenderErrorBox#14191 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
    .    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body
    .    constraints: MISSING
    .    size: MISSING
    .  child 2: RenderPositionedBox#34f21 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    .    needs compositing
    .    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 83.6); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body (can use size)
    .    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=711.3)
    .    size: Size(392.7, 711.3)
    .    alignment: center
    .    textDirection: ltr
    .    widthFactor: expand
    .    heightFactor: expand
    .  child 3: RenderConstrainedBox#67334 relayoutBoundary=up1
    .    needs compositing
    .    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.appBar (can use size)
    .    constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, 0.0<=h<=850.9)
    .    size: Size(392.7, 83.6)
    .    additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=83.6)
    .    child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#268b5 relayoutBoundary=up2
    .      needs compositing
    .      parentData: <none> (can use size)
    .      constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, 0.0<=h<=83.6)
    .      semantic boundary
    .      size: Size(392.7, 83.6)
    .      child: RenderAnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>#8f8ff relayoutBoundary=up3
    .        needs compositing
    .        parentData: <none> (can use size)
    .        constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, 0.0<=h<=83.6)
    .        size: Size(392.7, 83.6)
    .        child: RenderPhysicalModel#6f052 relayoutBoundary=up4
    .          needs compositing
    .          parentData: <none> (can use size)
    .          constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, 0.0<=h<=83.6)
    .          layer: PhysicalModelLayer#4e633
    .            engine layer: PhysicalShapeEngineLayer#9e72c
    .            elevation: 4.0
    .            color: MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xffff5722))
    .          size: Size(392.7, 83.6)
    .          elevation: 4.0
    .          color: MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xffff5722))
    .          shadowColor: MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xffff5722))
    .          shape: BoxShape.rectangle
    .          borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero
    .  child 4: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#b44d0 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
    .    needs compositing
    .    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 794.9); id=_ScaffoldSlot.bottomNavigationBar (can use size)
    .    constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, 0.0<=h<=850.9)
    ..    size: Size(392.7, 56.0)
    ..    child: RenderPhysicalModel#627c2 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
    ..      needs compositing
    ..      parentData: <none> (can use size)
    ..      constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, 0.0<=h<=850.9)
    ..      layer: PhysicalModelLayer#26163
    ..        engine layer: PhysicalShapeEngineLayer#3df82
    ..        elevation: 8.0
    ..        color: Color(0xfffafafa)
    ..      size: Size(392.7, 56.0)
    ..      elevation: 8.0
    ..      color: Color(0xfffafafa)
    ..      shadowColor: Color(0xfffafafa)
    ..      shape: BoxShape.rectangle
    ..      borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero
    ..      child: _RenderInkFeatures#64e29 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
    ..        parentData: <none> (can use size)
    ..        constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, 0.0<=h<=850.9)
    ..        size: Size(392.7, 56.0)
    ..        child: RenderConstrainedBox#c08b0 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
    ..          parentData: <none> (can use size)
    ..          constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, 0.0<=h<=850.9)
    ..          size: Size(392.7, 56.0)
    ..          additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, 56.0<=h<=Infinity)
    ..  child 5: RenderStack#b0601 relayoutBoundary=up1
    ..    parentData: offset=Offset(376.7, 778.9); id=_ScaffoldSlot.floatingActionButton (can use ize)
    ..    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=850.9)
    ..    size: Size(0.0, 0.0)
    ..    alignment: centerRight
    ..    textDirection: ltr
    ..    fit: loose
    ..    child 1: RenderTransform#7227d relayoutBoundary=up2
    ..      parentData: not positioned; offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
    ..      constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=850.9)
    ..      size: Size(0.0, 0.0)
    ..      transform matrix: [0] 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
    1] 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
    2] 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
    [3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
    ..      origin: null
    ..      alignment: center
    ..      textDirection: ltr
    ..      transformHitTests: true
    ..      child: RenderTransform#1577a relayoutBoundary=up3
    ..        parentData: <none> (can use size)
    ..        constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=850.9)
    ..        size: Size(0.0, 0.0)
    ..        transform matrix: [0] 0.7,0.7,0.0,0.0
    [1] -0.7,0.7,0.0,0.0
    [2] 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
    [3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
    ..        origin: null
    ..        alignment: center
    ..        textDirection: ltr
    ..        transformHitTests: true
    ====================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `ListView.builder` with `Expanded` widget, Also no need to use `SingleChildScrollView`.

Or You can use `SingleChildScrollView` with `ListView.builder` `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),`

Or just render item inside Column like

```dart
body: SingleChildScrollView(
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      ...dishdata.map((e) => Card(
            color: Colors.deepOrange,
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(e.name),
              trailing: Text(e.price),
              leading: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minHeight: 40,
                  minWidth: 40,
                  maxHeight: 50,
                  maxWidth: 50,
                ),
                child: Image.network(e.imageurl),
              ),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
          )),
    ],
  ),
),
);
```

There are others error I can see from console like range error,

Comment: it's not helping I changed  the dishdata list from final to static and one error got solved I still have range error I tried wrapping with an expanded widget and container both failed i don't know what is causing the error and  can't figure out or narrow down the error please help me solve this

Comment: The range error is most likely coming from last index. I suggest checking null 1st like `e.imageurl!=null?Image.network(e.imageurl):Text("cant find")` Also same goes for others variable

Answer (score 1):

This error is because you didn't set a height for the `ListView`, simply you can wrap the list view into a `Container` and give it a height number,
notice that if you gonna use `context.size.height`, it's better to use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`

if it doesn't work, try wrapping it into an `Expanded` widget

Comment: it's not helping I changed  the dishdata list from final to static and one error got solved I still have range error I tried wrapping with an expanded widget and container both failed i don't know what is causing the error and  can't figure out or narrow down the error please help me solve this